# Is there any open source web server monitor for IIS?

Tags: iis, web-server, monitoring, open-source

Are there any decent open source web server monitor app for IIS?  Something decent that could track for example:

- Activity/throughput
- Response time
- CPU usage
- Memory usage
- Disk usage
- Anything other useful stats

I've searched around code.google, codeplex, etc and haven't found much so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that information is exposed via perfmon counters, so you have multiple options:

1. An NMS that can read perfmon counters. nagios or zabbix are two I recommend. Zabbix is much, much easier to use if you're from a windows background, but both of them are way overkill for monitoring a single server
2. Use the built-in windows performance monitoring. It will give you live (and if you configure it, historical) statistics, but does little besides actually give you raw numbers.
3. Roll your own. Perfmon can be configured to log all that stuff into a CSV file or an SQL database. You can then analyse them however you need.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at Nagios but it looks like a LAMP style app.  It was very unclear to me on their site - what is required on the server to be able to run Nagios on windows?

Comment: @JK01 - you can't run Nagios on Windows. Nor Zabbix. These are standalone products that run on Linux that use use for monitoring your server remotely. Which is why they are overkill for your purposes.

Comment: @JK01 - in that case, just use the built in windows performance monitoring tools. They expose everything you need and don't even require installation.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios can monitor IIS: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/IIS

Nagios itself needs to run on Linux (or in a virtual Linux machine) but it can monitor IIS servers, too.

Answer (score 0):

Perfmon can get everything except the response time.   For that you could potentially leverage CURL (assuming an HTTP interface for your application).     There are lots of options which can get you both on the commercial front, all you need to do is ask management what is the value of the information so you can appropriately look at the commercial options and their prices matched with the expressed value.

If all screwdrivers are free and all hammers are expensive, would you really be better off driving nails with the butt end of a screwdriver?   Sometimes the "paid tool" has value in both efficiency and in interfaces that the free tool lacks which reduces the overall cost of ownership for the paid tool to the level at or below that of the free one.  (resisting the free dog or free car analogy...)